# Capybara + Selenium + Web scraping - parallel requests fail

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I use Capybara + ChromeDriver Selenium to scrape webpage.
During request the main goal is to download csv file.
Request takes about 15-20 seconds.

When I run 2 requests at the same time - it works well
3,4,5 etc parallel requests fail - looks like file is not being downloaded.

What's wrong here?
Here's my config.

Thanks!

```
require 'csv'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

class Scraper
  include Capybara::DSL
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
    options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1268')

    options.add_preference(:download, directory_upgrade: true,
                                  prompt_for_download: false,
                                  default_directory: DownloadHelpers.getpath)

    options.add_preference(:browser, set_download_behavior: { behavior: 'allow' })

    driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)

    bridge = driver.browser.send(:bridge)

    path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
    path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id

    bridge.http.call(:post, path,
      cmd: 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
      params: {
        behavior: 'allow',
        downloadPath: DownloadHelpers.getpath
      }
    )

    driver
  end

  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
end
```

**UPDATE**

How I run tasks - through rake task.

Scraper located inside rails lib folder.
Each request is called via rake task, that initializing rails environment and run scraper script.

Comment: How are you creating the parallel sessions?

Comment: Also - assuming you're using a recent selenium-webdriver you should be able to call `driver.browser.execute_cdp ...` rather than having to deal with `bridge` - although just calling `driver.browser.download_path = DownloadHelpers.getpath)` would probably do the same thing

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, updated question with answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running each task in a separate process there should be no conflict between them, which would then lead to the assumption that you're running into a resource (memory or cpu) limitation when trying to open multiple rails apps and browser instances. These could be causing the browser to fail to open, or they could just be slowing things down enough that you see flaky/failing behavior due to your scripts not being written to handle that cleanly.